# Logstash : Issue Parsing xml which does not have line break

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack

I am facing issue in processing xml files in logstash as the xml does not have line break and the whole file is just single line. Hence the multiline codec is not working. Does anyone have any custom code or any idea on how to resolve the issue?

[sample xml structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wQ1s.png)

```html
<Message><MessageID>786734787</MessageID><MessageUniqueID>PLANT_496734787</MessageUniqueID><Message>
```

Note:I am processing the output of IIB(ESQL)

Comment: The multiline codec is used to join multiple lines in one event. If the event is already on one line, the multiline won't have anything to do.

Comment: Yes..The event is one line.Since it does not have line break, logstash does not considering that as a XML file.